# How to remove space beyond axis limits in bokeh

Tags: bokeh

A typical bokeh scatter plot might look something like this: 
[image]

where both x and y limits are [0,1]. How can the extra space on the axes preceding the 0, and extending beyond the 1 be removed? Such that the final plot has its left corner be the coordinate (0,0) and the upper left and bottom right corners be (0,1) and (1,0) respectively, without any axis or ticks extending beyond those values.

Answer (score 6):

You can either set the range limits explicitly yourself:

```
p = figure(..., x_range=(0,1), y_range=(0,1))
```

Or, if you want auto-ranging, just without the padding:

```
p.x_range.range_padding = 0
p.y_range.range_padding = 0
```